# Random list only with -1 and 1

Tags: python, list, random

I need to create random list which consists only of -1 and 1 like -1,1,1,-1,-1 (without zeros). 
My current coding adds 0 that doesn't suite me.

```
import random
for x in range(10):
    print (random.randint(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), which randomly selects `k` elements from a given sequence, avoiding this way the need for any looping:

```
random.choices([-1,1], k=10)
#[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: this is more than 2 times faster than list comprehension

Comment: Or without a list: `random.randint(0,1)*2-1`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> [random.choice([-1, 1]) for _ in range(10)]
[1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
for x in range(10): 
    print (random.choice([-1,1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
[random.choice((-1, 1)) for _ in range(10)]
```

`random.choice()` selects a random element from a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

random.choice([value1, value2]), used to print one of the values within a list, example:

```py
import random

num = random.choice([-1, 1])
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

1. Generate a 10 bit random number in 0..1023.
2. Express the number as a binary text string, making sure to include all leading zeros.
3. Read the string, outputting "-1" for every zero and "1" for every one.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer incorporates Lee Daniel Crocker's comment.  He should post an answer of his own, then I will delete this one:

```
[random.randint(0,1)*2-1 for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if you don't want `-1` and `1` to be generated with the equal probabilities, and you do not want to install some math packages(such as `numpy`), you could also use the following method: say, you want there be 3 times more `1`s than `-1`s. Then the idea is that you generate a random number from `0` to `100`. If the number you generate is larger than `25`, append `1`, otherwise, append `-1`.

This can be expressed in the following one liner:

```
import random
[1 if random.randint(0,100)>25 else -1 for _ in range(25)]
```

This is quite a generic approach and allows one to easily control their distribution without external dependencies.